# Prevent chrome from changing text size

Tags: css, google-chrome

There is an option in chrome that lets you change default font size (Small, Medium, Large, Very Large) and appearently the

`-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;`

line isn't supported anymore. Is there any other way I can prevent chrome from changing font size?

Comment: Doesn't it work only for mobile devices?

Comment: That could be possible.. well im trying to figure out an alternative for desktop

Comment: Can you add more information. Why would chrome try to change your text size? Why dont you urself set the text size that you want? It is impossible to answer this question in any meaningfull way as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome as any other browser has default values for how elements should look.
The best way to get what you want is to implement a css script that resets all the different elements to values you know, and from their set the elements to a new desired value.

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,p,a {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

You can also implement media-queries to change behavior as viewport change.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I only changed font size by em, I solved my problem by adding a body style  with font-size:16px;   

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, probably, is to operate backwards: instead of preventing the page to change the fonts size, you might want to re-calculate it based on the zoomed level in the user's window.

Have a look at this question, you can try to use the described methods to detect the zoom level in the browser and apply a "counter-zoom" to reset it to your default font-size: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

E.g.: 
If the users zoom at 120% you want to set your font-size to 83.3333%

The formula is simply

```
function yourFontSize(zoomLevel){
    return 100/zoomLevel*100
}
```

More examples:

- If the users zoom at 110% `yourFontSize(110)  // returns 90.9090909090909`
- If the users zoom at 120% `yourFontSize(120)  // returns 83.33333333333334`
- If the users zoom at 150% `yourFontSize(150)  // returns 66.66666666666666`
- And so forth

Comment: Zoom level and font size change are different settings in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery, I force the font-size to a specific size. Open your page, right click for Inspect. Minimize-maximize and when the text shrinks, at the top right corner you will see the screen size, force it like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 400 && $(window).width() < 1000)
   $('#myParagraph').css('font-size', '40px');
});
```